# Postgres: Select where all rows with the same foreign key are null

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two tables `posts` and `authors`. An author has many posts, so there's a foreign key `posts.author_id`. Post also has a column `approved_at` which is a `datetime`, and is `NULL` until the post is approved

So how can I select all authors who have **no** approved posts?

I can select all authors who have **at least one** approved post with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM authors
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT a.id FROM authors a
    JOIN posts p ON a.id = p.author_id
    AND p.approved_at IS NOT NULL
)
```

But I can't figure out how to do the opposite: I want to select **all authors** where **all** of their associated posts have `approved_at = NULL`. How can I select this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select authors who have either no posts at all or all posts are not approved (or, as you said - authors who have **no** approved posts), use `not exists`, for me it's most readable way:

```
select a.*
from authors as a
where
    not exists
    (
        select *
        from posts as p
        where p.author_id = a.id and p.approved_at is not null
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If postgres supports this syntax, try this approach

```
SELECT * FROM authors
WHERE id IN
(
   SELECT a.id FROM authors a
    JOIN posts p ON a.id = p.author_id
    AND p.approved_at is NULL

    except

    SELECT a.id FROM authors a
    JOIN posts p ON a.id = p.author_id
    AND p.approved_at IS NOT NULL
)
```